# Set variable after selecting spinner item - Android

Tags: android, variables, spinner, toast

I want to set a variable after an item is picked in a spinner. Since I am new to Java I don't know what the best way is to do this. I tried to test the item after it is selected but I can't get it to work.
A new variable has to be created and the values must be 0.5 for Beginner, 1 for Advanced and 1.5 for Pro. As long as I'm developing my app I also want it to display a toast message with the value of the variable when an item is selected.

Hope someone can help me, because I'm stuck at the moment.

My Java code:

```
public class AlbumsActivity  extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.albums_layout);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_experience);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.experience_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
            Object test = spinner.getSelectedItem();
            if "Pro".equals(test) {
                // Do something
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +
                    parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Do Nothing
        }
    }

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
}
```

layout xml

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_Experience"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/experience_prompt" />
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner_experience"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:prompt="@string/experience_prompt" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my strings for the spinner:

```
<resources>

<string name="experience_prompt">Select your experience</string>
<string-array name="experience_array">
    <item>Beginner</item>
    <item>Advanced</item>
    <item>Pro</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head (so could be typos and other errors):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
         if(pos == 0) {
            // Beginner
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Beginner = 0.5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if(pos == 1) {
            // Advanced
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Advanced = 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Pro
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Pro = 1.5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

You could spruce it up a lot with a HashMap to hold key:value pairs for the different levels you are suggesting here, but if you only have three levels, then this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlbumsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_experience);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.experience_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                Object test = spinner.getSelectedItem();
                Toast.makeText(AlbumsActivity.this, "The planet is " +
                        spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `Object test = spinner.getSelectedItem();` with `String test = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();`

Also `parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()` will return the Id of the view inside the Spinner not the text. To get this text use:

```
TextView TV=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
```

and replace `parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()` with `TV.getText().toString();`